# Component DB Query (Yii)

Tags: activerecord, yii, components

I'll first describe my initial problem - I have a few site global variables (such as whether I'm online/offline, the price of the item etc).. I was wondering how best to store/retrieve these as they are needed on most pages.

In the end after some guidance I've opted to store them in a DB and create a component class (in Yii) to access them from where ever: e.g.  `echo Yii::app()->variables->price`

I'm new to Yii, and I've been searching around but cannot find out how to properly interface a DB (AR Style) connection with a component.. So far I've created a Model class and the DB with columns `'id', 'name', 'value'`

Just to get the hang of it I'm writing a method: `getTestValue()` in my component class, but I just don't know how to go about retrieving the row with name `test` using Yii's ActiveRecord. Could someone point me in the right direction please? :)

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
function getTestValue(){
  $myvalobj = YourModelClass::model()->findByAttributes(array('name'=>'test'));
  if($myvalobj!==null)
     return $myvalobj->value;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer solves your issue, you should mark that as "correct".